# Black screen when running VLC from systemd

Tags: systemd, vlc

I want to display a video on a monitor via systemd. my systemd script looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=example script

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=0
ExecStart=bash /home/pi/script.sh
Type=simple
User=pi

ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall vlc

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and is placed at /etc/systemd/system/vlc.service. The shell script is this:

```
DISPLAY=:0 vlc --fullscreen /home/pi/file.mp4
```

running the script manually as the pi user works fine - the video and sound play. Running the script via `systemctl start vlc` loads up VLC and "plays" the file (the correct runtime is shown and the scrub bar moves) but no sound or video plays.

I've tested this on a pi zero w and pi 4b and both have the same issue, running the latest, updated raspberry pi OS image. What should I try next?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this in the meantime? I have the same issue since I switched from omxplayer to cvlc (because omxplayer is not running anymore on newer OSes)

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution for me [in the RPi forums](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=323808#p1944394), maybe it helps you too.

Add (or change) this line in `/boot/config.txt`:

```
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
```

From what I understood, `kms` runs all on the kernel and has more restrictive permissions on what may paint on layers, and `fkms` (fake kms) still allows VLC to paint on the screen when started as systemd service.